# Protégé dataTime restriction

Tags: xsd, owl, protege, protege4, manchester-syntax

I've a Data Property ShowTime with domain Show and range `xsd:dateTime`. I'd like to know if there is a way to assert that the dataTime range must be included in "2018-01-01TX:X:X", in order to have a fixed date and a variable hour on that date.

I've tried with Manchester Syntax:

```
xsd:dateTime[>="2018-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime, <"2018-01-01T00:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime]
```

But told me that the syntax is not correct.

P.S. I'm using HermiT.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

**edited**

Concrete example. Suppose we have a `Show` class, which represents the concept of a cinema show. Each show has date and a start time. So, we can trivially represent these informations through a data property `showDateTime` with domain `Show` and range `xsd:dateTime` (something like "2018-01-16T18:00:00").

The problem is that i need to categorize each show in a daily time slot (morning, afternoon, early evening, late night) according to the start time only. I tried with SWRL, property restriction... I haven't found a way to tell the reasoner not to consider the date, which obviously takes precedence over the time and messes me up.

So, i thought of dividing date and time into two separate properties (`showDate` and `showTime`), always of type xsd: dateTime, and placing a restriction on `showTime` binding it to have a fixed date (ex. 2018-01-01). In this way I could define the MorningShow class as follow:

```
 showTime some xsd:dateTime[>= "2018-01-01T07:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime ,
 <= "2018-01-01T13:00:00"^^xsd:dateTime]
```

This is the reason for my question.

Answer (score 2):

Manchester syntax enables you to create OWL ontologies. However, the semantics of OWL does not allow for what you are trying to do.

**EDIT for your updated question**

Defining the `MorningShow` class as you described is not going to work because:

(1) There is no way to dynamically change the definition of the class as you described.

(2) More importantly, it goes against the notion of a class which gives a fixed description of a set to which individuals belong/don't belong. What you have in mind boils down to a different `MorningShow` class for every possible date.

I was thinking there may be a way in SWRL in Protege to apply some function that will extract only the time. However, this is not the case.

The only other options are:

(1) Consider using the [Time Ontology in OWL](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-time/), though it may be an overkill.

(2) Define your own `DateTime` class which is the domain for the following data properties:

i. `date` with range `xsd:dateTime`,

ii. `hours` with range `xsd:byte`,

iii. `minutes` with range `xsd:byte`

```
ObjectProperty: showTime
    Domain:Show
    Range: DateTime

DataProperty: date
    Domain: DateTime
    Range: xsd:dateTime

DataProperty: hours
    Domain: DateTime
    Range:  xsd:byte[>= "0"^^xsd:byte , < "24"^^xsd:byte]

DataProperty: minutes
    Domain: DateTime
    Range: xsd:byte[>= "0"^^xsd:byte , < "60"^^xsd:byte]

Class: Afternoon
    EquivalentTo: hours some xsd:byte[>= "12"^^xsd:byte , < "17"^^xsd:byte]
    SubClassOf: DateTime

Class: DateTime
Class: Morning
    EquivalentTo: hours some xsd:byte[< "12"^^xsd:byte]
    SubClassOf: DateTime

Class: Show
    SubClassOf: showTime some ShowTime

Class: ShowTime
    SubClassOf: showTime exactly 1 DateTime

Individual: dt
    Facts: hours  "8"^^xsd:byte
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I apologize if I have not explained well. I modified the question by adding more information. If you can help me, you'd really help me.

Comment: @Cilla Your edit does make your question much clearer. Thanks. I will re-visit and hopefully I will be able to post an update in the next 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you so much again!

Comment: can i do math with datetime in OWL ?

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse `showTime` objectproperty domain is `show`, and `showTime` class is defined as `SubClassOf: showTime exactly 1 DateTime`. regarding to `show` domain , is that a correct definition ?

Comment: @amin Yes. You can see more about this on my blog [here](https://henrietteharmse.com/2017/11/03/associations-between-classes/).

Comment: @HenrietteHarmse thanks. I reviewed blog post, but i didn't get the answer. here we have a `showtime` objectProperty with domain `show` , that is assigned to a class (showTime class) that is NOT of `show` type.in fact it may infer that `show` and `showTime` are the same class